# Sql - selecting, then divide the count of result with the count of table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have these data in my table named tbl_casebase :

[image: tbl_casebase]

In the column kd_penyakit known that P01 there are 3 data, P02 are 2 data, P03 are 4 data, and P04 are 2 data.

Then I did a search of kd_penyakit based on kd_gejala: G01, G03, G04, and G07. Then the result is as follows:

[image: Select query]

From the search results known that P01 there are 2 data, P02 are 2 data, P03 are 2 data, and P04 there is only 1 data.

What I want to do is how I do a search like above, then the result (ie 2, 2, 2, 1) is divided by the calculation of kd_penyakit from the tbl_casebase table (ie 3, 2, 4, 2) so that it becomes 2/3, 2/2, 2/4, 1/2 and the result is 0.6666; 1; 0.5; 0.5.

Is there a query that can do that?

Comment: Yes, there is a query for that, but I doubt anyone will give you a hand with producing it when the quality of your question is so low. Would suggest taking a look at how to ask questions section.

Comment: Sorry my engslish's still bad

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you seem to want:

```
select kd_penyakit,
       avg(case when kd_gejala in ('G01', 'G02', 'G03', 'G07') then 1.0 else 0.0 end)
from tbl_casebase
group by kd_penyakit;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the result still wrong. The calculation result that should be obtained is 0.666; 1; 0.5; 0.5. But in your answer the result is 1; 0,5; 0,25; 0,5 @Gordon